# Are Android's "unique" Calendars._ID values reused if the calendar is remotely deleted?

Tags: android, calendar

Working with the Calendar Provider APIs has led to a bit of a question about the unique `_ID` column provided by Android.

This column seems to be the primary and preferred way to query for a calendar, but also to specify which calendar an event should be created on.

What we've seemed to discover is that these `_ID` values are actually recycled (no `AUTOINCREMENT`) if a calendar is deleted remotely and that deletion is sync'd. A future calendar may be given the old calendar's `_ID`.

So for example if we have:

```
_ID, DISPLAY_NAME
1, "First Calendar"
2, "Second Calendar"
3, "Third Calendar"
```

Then we delete the "Third Calendar" on `calendar.google.com`. We resync on Android. We then *add* "Fourth Calendar" on `calendar.google.com`. We resync on Android.

Now we have:

```
_ID, DISPLAY_NAME
1, "First Calendar"
2, "Second Calendar"
3, "Fourth Calendar"
```

Let's say in our `SharedPreference` we had stored a reference to the "Third Calendar" via the `_ID` of `3`.

If we were to go create and event on that calendar, we'd be doing it on the wrong calendar without really knowing it.

Is this behavior something that is documented or well known, and if true how could we safely store a reference to a calendar in our application without the potential of it being a completely different calendar later on?

Android docs, for reference:
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#calendar